# Show User and their ForecastingQuota

Tags: apex, list, user, quota

I have a List of User who are enable to have ForecastingQuota:

```
List<User> resultsusers = new List<User>();
    resultsusers = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND ForecastEnabled = TRUE LIMIT 999];
```

And a List of the ForecastingQuota:

```
List<ForecastingQuota> resultsquotas = new List<ForecastingQuota>();
    resultsquotas = [SELECT Id,QuotaAmount,QuotaOwnerId FROM ForecastingQuota ORDER BY StartDate ASC];
```

I have make a Map of the User Id and his ForecastingQuotaAmount :

```
Map<Id, ForecastingQuota> fqsByOwnerId = new Map<Id, ForecastingQuota>();
        for (ForecastingQuota fq : resultsquotas)
        {
            fqsByOwnerId.put(fq.QuotaOwnerId, fq);
        }


        // new map of quotas keyed by all user ids
    Map<Id, ForecastingQuota> allUserFqsByOwnerId = new Map<Id, ForecastingQuota>();
        for (User u : resultsusers)
        {
              allUserFqsByOwnerId.put(u.id, fqsByOwnerId.get(u.id));
        }
```

But this Map show only User who have already a QuotaAmount, and not also the User who haven't a Quota, but I want the both in the same List.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest method would be to add a [Ternary statement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm), which acts as a shortcut for an if-else statement. The statement checks if the key already exists in the map using the `containsKey` map method, and either adds the data already in the map, or provides empty data.

The statement:

```
fqsByOwnerId.containsKey(u.id) ? fqsByOwnerId.get(u.id) : new ForecastingQuota()
```

Ends up looking something like this when fully expanded:

```
if ( fqsByOwnerId.containsKey(u.id) )
{ 
    fqsByOwnerId.get(u.id); 
} 
else 
{ 
    new ForecastingQuota();
}
```

You can see how using this in your code would allow you to add an empty `ForecastingQuota` without modifying your loop.

```
for (User u : resultsusers)
{
    allUserFqsByOwnerId.put(u.id, fqsByOwnerId.containsKey(u.id) ? fqsByOwnerId.get(u.id) : new ForecastingQuota());
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's work perfectly, but the name of the user does not appear when the user does not have a quota.